# calculate logarithm and mean, add the result to dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, logging, mean

In the following dataset

```
  code test1 ref1 test2 ref2
1    A  19.0 19.5  31.8   33
2    B  17.6 19.5  29.1   33
3    C  19.6 19.5  31.4   33
4    D  20.0 19.5  33.5   33
5    E  17.8 19.5  30.5   33
6    F  18.6 19.5  31.7   33
7    G  19.0 19.5  31.2   33
8    H  18.2 19.5  29.6   33
9    I  18.3 19.5  30.3   33
```

I want to calculate the difference between logs of the "test" and "ref" columns.

```
log(test1)- log(ref1) = a
log(test2)- log(ref2) = b
```

Then I want to calculate the mean of a and b for each row and save the result on a new column in the dataset.

I tried this function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x[paste0(x, sep = "_log")] <<- log(x[x]) 
}

sapply(names(x)[-1], f)
```

but I can only calculate the logs of each column and add the result to new columns.

If I continue like this, my dataset will be too long.
Could anyone help me to create a code that performs all calculations and add a single column as the final result?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's cool to `paste` the numbers to the names. Here a solution that fits to your example. If you have four pairs just use `1:4` in the `sapply`.

```
rowMeans(sapply(1:2, \(i) 
                log(dat[[paste0('test', i)]]) - log(dat[[paste0('ref', i)]])), 
         na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] -0.03150838 -0.11414248 -0.02229228  0.02017784 -0.08499844 -0.04372188
# [7] -0.04103248 -0.08886304 -0.07443663
```

*Note:* `\(i)` means `function(i)` in R versions prior to R4.1.0.

Comment: Many thanks. R interprets "\" as an unexpected token. Could you please help?

Comment: That's great. It works. For the rows that I have NAs, it returns NA as mean. However I want to calculate the mean of 3 pairs when 1 pair in NA. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Azy Just add `, na.rm=TRUE`, see update. Did you read the _Note_ just use `function(i)` or update your R?

Comment: Great :) It works with na.rm=TRUE. Yes I have to update my R. For now, I changed the \(i) by function(i) and it worked properly. Many thanks jay.sf. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(a = log(test1)- log(ref1), b = log(test2)- log(ref2),
       Mean = rowMeans(cbind(a, b), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
 code test1 ref1 test2 ref2            a           b        Mean
1    A  19.0 19.5  31.8   33 -0.025975486 -0.03704127 -0.03150838
2    B  17.6 19.5  29.1   33 -0.102515564 -0.12576939 -0.11414248
3    C  19.6 19.5  31.4   33  0.005115101 -0.04969967 -0.02229228
4    D  20.0 19.5  33.5   33  0.025317808  0.01503788  0.02017784
5    E  17.8 19.5  30.5   33 -0.091216008 -0.07878088 -0.08499844
6    F  18.6 19.5  31.7   33 -0.047252885 -0.04019088 -0.04372188
7    G  19.0 19.5  31.2   33 -0.025975486 -0.05608947 -0.04103248
8    H  18.2 19.5  29.6   33 -0.068992871 -0.10873320 -0.08886304
9    I  18.3 19.5  30.3   33 -0.063513406 -0.08535985 -0.07443663
```

---

Or if there are many pairs, do this automatically

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Mean = rowMeans(across(starts_with('test'), 
    ~ log(.) - log(get(str_replace(cur_column(), "test", "ref")))), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
code test1 ref1 test2 ref2        Mean
1    A  19.0 19.5  31.8   33 -0.03150838
2    B  17.6 19.5  29.1   33 -0.11414248
3    C  19.6 19.5  31.4   33 -0.02229228
4    D  20.0 19.5  33.5   33  0.02017784
5    E  17.8 19.5  30.5   33 -0.08499844
6    F  18.6 19.5  31.7   33 -0.04372188
7    G  19.0 19.5  31.2   33 -0.04103248
8    H  18.2 19.5  29.6   33 -0.08886304
9    I  18.3 19.5  30.3   33 -0.07443663
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(code = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I"), test1 = c(19, 17.6, 19.6, 20, 17.8, 18.6, 19, 18.2, 18.3
), ref1 = c(19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5
), test2 = c(31.8, 29.1, 31.4, 33.5, 30.5, 31.7, 31.2, 29.6, 
30.3), ref2 = c(33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: Many thanks Akrun. This was great. I could finally create my dataset as I wanted. I have another question. I took a sample from my dataset to ask this question. In my real dataset, I have 8 columns (4 tests and 4 refs) and sometimes I have NAs. By using this code, I get NA in the mean column for the rows that miss only one data. How can I calculate the mean even when I don't have data in all 8 columns? thank you again

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing things like this often with your data, you might find it more convenient to store the data in "long" format, because then operations like this can be done a little more naturally

Make into long format

```
df1_long <- 
  df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(names_pattern = '(test|ref)(\\d+)',
                 names_to = c('name', 'num'),
                 cols = -1) %>% 
    group_by(code, num) %>% 
    arrange(name, .by_group = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 36 x 4
# # Groups:   code, num [18]
# code  name  num   value
# <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#   1 A     ref   1      19.5
#   2 A     test  1      19  
#   3 A     ref   2      33  
#   4 A     test  2      31.8
#   5 B     ref   1      19.5
#   6 B     test  1      17.6
#   7 B     ref   2      33  
#   8 B     test  2      29.1
#   9 C     ref   1      19.5
#   10 C     test  1      19.6
#   # … with 26 more rows
```

With data in this shape it's more obvious how to get the summary by group

```
df1_long %>% 
  summarise(dlog = diff(log(value))) %>% 
  summarise(mean_dlog = mean(dlog))
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
# code  mean_dlog
# <chr>     <dbl>
#   1 A       -0.0315
#   2 B       -0.114 
#   3 C       -0.0223
#   4 D        0.0202
#   5 E       -0.0850
#   6 F       -0.0437
#   7 G       -0.0410
#   8 H       -0.0889
#   9 I       -0.0744
```

You could also use this method while still keeping your data in the same format, but in that case you may as well use the method in the other answers

```
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_pattern = '(test|ref)(\\d+)',
               names_to = c('name', 'num'),
               cols = -1) %>% 
  group_by(code, num) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  summarise(dlog = diff(log(value))) %>% 
  summarise(mean_dlog = mean(dlog)) %>% 
  mutate(.data = df1, mean_dlog = .$mean_dlog)
# code test1 ref1 test2 ref2   mean_dlog
# 1    A  19.0 19.5  31.8   33 -0.03150838
# 2    B  17.6 19.5  29.1   33 -0.11414248
# 3    C  19.6 19.5  31.4   33 -0.02229228
# 4    D  20.0 19.5  33.5   33  0.02017784
# 5    E  17.8 19.5  30.5   33 -0.08499844
# 6    F  18.6 19.5  31.7   33 -0.04372188
# 7    G  19.0 19.5  31.2   33 -0.04103248
# 8    H  18.2 19.5  29.6   33 -0.08886304
# 9    I  18.3 19.5  30.3   33 -0.07443663
```